# Are all the groups of order $n$ contained in $S_n$?

Tags: finite-groups

I want to know if I can considere any group of order $n$ is isomorphic to one of $S_n$. Is that true? I can't find a proof.

Comment: Yes, the group acts on itself by multiplication from the left, and this gives an injective homomorphism from the group to $S_n$.

Comment: This is known as Cayley's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem

Comment: Thank you. Now is clear. I didn't know this theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(To remove this from unanswered questions)

Yes, this is known as [Cayley's theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem)

Label the elements of $G$ as $g_1$, $g_2$, up to $g_n$. For each $g_i$ define a permutation $\pi_i$ such that if $g_i \cdot g_j = g_k$ then $\pi_i(j) = k$. Since multiplication is invertible in a group, $\pi_i$ is a bijection, and since multiplication is closed, $\pi_i$ is a permutation. If $\pi_i( \pi_j(k)) =\pi_i(l) = m$, then $g_j \cdot g_k = g_l$ and $g_i \cdot g_l = g_m$ so $(g_i \cdot g_j) \cdot g_k = g_m$. Hence if $g_i \cdot g_j = g_p$, then $\pi_i \circ \pi_j = \pi_p$. Thus the function $g_i \mapsto \pi_i$ is a homomorphism. It is clearly injective, since if $g_1$ is the identity of $G$, then $\pi_i(1) = i$ identifies each $\pi_i$; that is, the inverse is $\pi \mapsto g_{\pi(1)}$. Hence we have an isomorphism of $G$ with a subgroup of $S_n$.

The subgroups of this form are called **regular subgroups**.

One can also include the automorphism group by taking a normalizer (this gives the **holomorph**).  Recognizing such holomorphs can be very useful, and often described as permutation groups with a **regular normal subgroup**, such as the affine groups.